# Python code not working for datetime and if statements

Tags: python

Why doesn't this code work? it just prints 's' and "bad"

```
import datetime
import csv

format = "%H%M"
today = datetime.datetime.today()
s = today.strftime(format)

print s

if s == 1029:
    print ("Good")
else:
    print ("Bad")
```

Comment: Are you missing something in the code? It should just be printing "Bad"

Comment: `s == 1029:` is always false... s will never be an integer

Comment: `s` is a string and you're comparing it with an integer. Not only that, but your result should be 'correct' only one minute per day.

Comment: Variable `s`is a string.  Try `if s == "1029":` (also adjust for the current date/time)

Comment: if the time is 10:29 it should print Good, which where I am it was, well was. I kept changing it to the correct time and rerunning the code but I never work

Comment: Hint: `print type(s)`

Comment: Like the people above have said, `s` is of type `str`. However, `1029` is of time `int`. A String will never be equal to an Int. You would have to replace `1029` with `'1029'` (notice the quotes).

Comment: thank you, it was because s was a string, works now thank you. How would I make s not a string because I need to do    if s >= "1037": and I don't think I can do that with strings?

Comment: Also consider using freezegun instead of continuously changing your code whenever you want to run it. https://github.com/spulec/freezegun

Comment: never mind it works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast your time string to an integer

```
import time
print "Good" if int(time.strftime('%H%M')) == 1029 else "Bad"
```

Reason: `strftime` returns a string, and you compared to a number, which is always false